# Stub functions before running script as child process

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, sinon, stub

I have mostly only seen mocks and stubs used in automated testing. But I wanted to stub methods for manually testing my app. This way I can run my server and test my app manually in my browser and when I press a button to buy an item for example, the backend will have been stubbed so that the call to stripe is stubbed with a fake call to stripe.

I want to create a test environment to do this. In this test environment I want to stub some methods, like api calls to stripe. I would think one would create this test environment by writing a script that stubs methods and then launches the app from a child process after the stubs are set.

But I'm having trouble stubbing methods before launching a script as a child process. When I launch a file using `child_process`, stubbing isn't working.

To recreate:

1. Go to [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-fog-fm1pu?file=/src/runStubbedScript.js) sandbox
2. Go to the terminal and click the + button to open a non-read-only terminal
3. Run `node src/runStubbedScript.js`

In the terminal you will get:

`making an http request to Stripe. This may take a while...`

But I would expect the stub to replace it and give me `skipping call to stripe`.

**How do I stub methods before launching a script?**

#### Code

`index.js`:

```js
const stripeInterface = require('./stripeInterface');

stripeInterface.charge();
```

`stripeInterface.js`:

```js
const stripe = {
  charge: () => console.log('making an http request to Stripe. This may take a while...'),
};
module.exports = stripe;
```

`runStubbedScript.js`
Here I try to stub the Stripe interface and then launch `index.js`:

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const stripe = require('./stripeInterface');

sinon.stub(stripe, 'charge').callsFake(() => console.log('skipping call to stripe'));
exec('node index.js', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
  if (error !== null) {
    console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of executing a `child_process` I realized I could just `require` the file and it would do what I wanted:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const stripe = require('./stripeInterface');

sinon.stub(stripe, 'charge').callsFake(() => console.log('skipping call to stripe'));

require('./index'); // this runs index and the stripe function is stubbed
```

Comment: Just a note: Sinon is not really doing anything "magic" when stubbing functions. It is essentially just overwriting a property. So if you do not want any of the verification functionality of Sinon, just replace the props yourself; less code and easier to understand:
`stripe.charge = () => console.log('skipping call to stripe')`.